# MVC Routing match all routes except resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a angularJS application. I've created a controller/action that returns a rendered index.cshtml on any request. This is my only mvc4 controller. I use the webapi for all other behavior. The client-side should only handling the routes. Works well so far.

```
RouteExistingFiles = false;

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index" }
);
```

The problem is that this solution matches resources like "localhost/favicon.ico, localhost/template.html".
Can i prevent or ignore all request like this ?

Comment: if you are specifying "RouteExistingFiles = false" then it should not map resources like .html

Comment: it should but it don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`IgnoreRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#scenarios_when_routing_is_not_applied) so the routing module ignores requests for those resources, for example:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{templateName}.html");
```

These have to be added before your current `Default` route.

Comment: Yes but these are just examples and not really a good solution trough. Than i need to use regex as well. Wait some time. If there is nothing better you get your accept.

Comment: Yes, the pattern for `IgnoreRoute` can be as complex as needed, and you can also add constraints as for regular routes

Comment: If you place your templates/css/js in known folders you could possibly achive that using `routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}");` and `routes.IgnoreRoute("templates/{*pathInfo}");`. Other than that you may want to rethink you catch-all `Default` route?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, then routing module ignores requests for any **.html** and **.ico** files :-

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allhtml}", new {allhtml=@".*\.html(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"})
```